# Unit test of "Gaderypoluki" algorithm

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to encode/decode a string by "Gaderypoluki" algorithm.
Everything works, if I do it in my own solution, a code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace algorithm
{
    public class Gaderypoluki
    {
        public static Tuple<string, int[]> Encode(string key, string toEncrypt)
        {
            int[] iterations = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            if (key.Length % 2 == 0)
            { 
                if (key.Length == key.Distinct().Count())
                {
                    var encodedText = new StringBuilder(toEncrypt);
                    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.Length ; i++)
                    {

                        for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j += 2)
                        {

                            if (key[j] == toEncrypt[i])
                            {
                                encodedText[i] = key[j + 1];
                                iterations[j / 2] += 1;

                            }
                            else if (key[j+1] == toEncrypt[i])
                            {
                                encodedText[i] = key[j];
                                iterations[j / 2] += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return Tuple.Create(encodedText.ToString(), iterations);
                }
                else throw new ArgumentException("Key cannot contain the same chars");
            }
            else throw new ArgumentException("You have to put a key which is dividable by 2");
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var key = "gaderypoluki";
            var encodedText = "gug mg iptg";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encode(key, encodedText).Item1);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, solution mades everything well. 
Result will be "ala ma kota", so it's a good result.
But the problem starts, when I want to test it by auto test such as:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace algorithm
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GaderypolukiTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var key = "GADERYPOLUKI";
            var encodedText = "gug mg iptg";
            var expectedText = "ala ma kota";
            Tuple<string, int[]> actual = Gaderypoluki.Encode(key, encodedText);


            Assert.AreEqual(expectedText.ToLower(), actual.Item1.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I start a test, a method `Encode()`does completely nothing. While debugging, even if `if (key[j] == toEncrypt[i])` equals, compiler says it doesn't and goes on.
I really don't know why, was searching a lot about this issue but this problem is not resolved yet(or I could search better).
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your unit test, you define your `key` as `"GADERYPOLUKI"` and in your implementation you do `key[j] == toEncrypt[i]`, which is **case sensitive**. This works in your application because you define the `key` in all lower case. So either:

- Update your test to have the key be in all lower case
- Update your implementation to do a case insensitive comparison

Answer (score -1):

Take in consideration, the differences between your test, and at the test method.

In test method

```
var key = "GADERYPOLUKI";
```

Your test

```
var key = "gaderypoluki";
```

C# see the differences between capital and small letters;)
just add key.ToLower();

Link: https://github.com/MrSwistak/GaderypolukiTestProject

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14406240)

Comment: Thanks for those hints;) Next time I'll stick to this rules